# Leaflet map does not display path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, leaflet

I am trying out the basic features of Leaflet with Angular. I have the following html piece:

In the controller, I have done the following:

```
$scope.markers = [
                 {
                    lat: 52.5,
                    lng: 0,
                    focus: true,
                    //message: "Hey, drag me if you want",
                    title: "Marker",
                    draggable: true,
                    label: {
                        message: "Hey, drag me if you want",
                        options: {
                            noHide: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    lat: 51,
                    lng: 0,
                    focus: true,
                    title: "Marker",
                    draggable: true,
                    label: {
                        message: "Hey, drag me if you want",
                        options: {
                            noHide: true
                        }
                    }
                }

            ];
$scope.europeanPaths = {
                p1: {
                    color: 'red',
                    weight: 8,
                    latlngs: [
                        { lat: 51.50, lng: -0.082 },
                        { lat: 48.83, lng: 2.37 },
                        { lat: 41.91, lng: 12.48 }
                    ],
                    message: "<h3>Route from London to Rome</h3><p>Distance: 1862km</p>",
                }
            };
$scope.london = {
                lat: 51.505,
                lng: -0.09,
                zoom: 5
            };
```

The markers nicely show up and the map gets centred over London. But the path doesn't get displayed. When I debugged through the "paths" directive, I found that a layer with the path co-ordinates get added to the map.

I am pretty new to Angular, hence trying to understand how things are working behind the scenes. TIA.

(I am trying to create a Fiddle for the same!)

Comment: Please add code how are you setting up map (add markers, paths).

Comment: I have used the leaflet directive as follows:
<leaflet defaults="defaults" center="london" markers="markers" paths="europeanPaths" height="240px" id="areamap"></leaflet>
According to the demo on the leaflet directive website, this should work(unless I am missing something!)

Comment: Looks OK for me, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0hk935u/1/). Maybe outdated libraries or you are adding them in wrong direction?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fiddle. Can you please explain what you mean by "adding them in wrong direction"?

Comment: I mean adding script files to html file in proper order. AngularJS, then Leaflet, then Leaflet-directive.

Comment: I am adding angular(~1.3.x), leadflet(~0.7.3), leaflet.label(~0.2.1), leaflet-directive(~0.7.9) in that order. The  layer gets added, the path gets added to the map object but the display is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and the reason was in included css with style

```
svg{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Correction

```
 .angular-leaflet-map svg{
   width: initial;
   height: initial;
 }
```

resolve the problem